# Erro: Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

Tags: ios, swift

Como corrijo o seguinte erro:

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

O erro é dado no trecho de código abaixo:

```
let frase = lblFrase.text

let textToShare = [ frase ]

///O erro esta nesta linha    
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.mail ]

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: não precisa adicionar UIActivityType aos elementos do excludedActivityTypes. Basta passar apenas os cases `[ .airDrop, .mail ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que a propriedade `text` do seu campo é do tipo opcional `String?` e Swift é uma linguagem type inferred. Sendo assim o tipo do seu objeto frase também será `String?`. Para que isso não aconteça basta você usar um operador chamado nil coalescing operator `??` que te proporciona a oportunidade de escolher um valor padrão para o seu object caso text não tenha nenhum valor ou caso ele ainda não tenha sido inicializado.

Em vez de

```
let frase = lblFrase.text
```

Use

```
let frase = lblFrase.text ?? "default value"
```